# Proving the existence of $c>0$ such that $f(c)=0$ for a polynomial function

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, continuity, roots

Given the function $f(x)= x^5-3x^3-5$, prove there exists some $c>0$ such that $f(c)=0$.

Would it be sufficient to show that the polynomial is continuous on the interval  $(0,\infty),$ then invoking the IVT would give us the $f(c)=0$? If not, then how would you go about this?

Answer (score 1):

If you try using the IVT you'll see that it is in fact sufficient.
$f(0) = -5, f(2) = 3$. Can you do the rest?

Comment: Well $c>0$ in this problem, but I get your point.

Comment: The IVT states that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, there is a $c\in (a, b)$ so that $f(c) = k$ for any $k$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. That means evaluating $f(0)$ is fine, you don't have to do something messy like $f(0.1)$.

Comment: @ContraModernistae Your comment doesn't make any sense to me.